# GridLine does not appear when I bind data with MVVM in Helixtoolkit

Tags: wpf, mvvm, helix-3d-toolkit

As I mentioned in the title, the GridLine is not displayed in the Helixtoolkit MVVM instance. I couldn't find the source of the problem. My application is as follows.

```
        <HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">

        <HelixToolkit:GridLinesVisual3D Width="600"
                                        Length="600"
                                        Thickness="0.1"
                                        MinorDistance="5"
                                        MajorDistance="10"
                                        Fill="Black"
                                        Visible="True" />

    </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are overwriting.

There are a few ways to resolve this:

**Option 1**: Include the `GridLinesVisual3D` in your `Objects` dynamically (possibly in your `ViewModel`) and not inside the `HelixViewport3D` in the XAML.

```
<hx:HelixViewport3D ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}"/>
```

```cs
//Pseudo code in ViewModel, depends on how you are using it or on the type of "Objects"...
var myGrid = new GridLinesVisual3D();
Objects.Add(myGrid);
```

**Option 2**: You can put a `ModelVisual3D` (or other container, which one to use really depends on what you are doing) and pass your objects to it while keeping the `GridLinesVisual3D` defined inside the `HelixViewport3D`.

```
<hx:HelixViewport3D>
    <hx:SunLight/>
    <hx:GridLinesVisual3D ... />
    <ModelVisual3D Content="{Binding myModelVisual3D.Content}"/> 
</hx:HelixViewport3D>
```